# Flex / AIR local SQL support for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, on-duplicate-key

As the title says does the SQL implementation in Adobe's AIR platform support "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"? I am unable to get it to work but it is possible I am using wrong syntax especially if it's different from MySQL syntax. Documentation is very sparse for SQL in flex and the little that I found had no mention of ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. The error I get is quite meaningless: "Error #2044: Unhandled SQLErrorEvent:. errorID=3115, operation=execute , message=Error #3115: SQL Error. , details=near 'ON': syntax error"

The database file does not insert any values at all if I get the error.

```
var insertQuery:String = "INSERT INTO movies(id, title, type, date_added) VALUES('" +
movieData['id'] + "', '" +
movieData['title'] + "', '" +
movieData['type'] + "', '" +
"2012-01-18 06:05:01" +
"') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = 'TEST', type = 'movie', date_added = '2011-11-11 08:02:01'";
```

It works as expected without the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL for AIR is based on [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html). Although auto-resolve conflict resolution doesn't apply to foreign keys, it's easy to create an alternate using a `before insert trigger`.

Comment: I've just figured out that it's SQLite, but could you elaborate on the alternative?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table_name FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT 
    RAISE(ABORT, 'account_id violates foreign key account(id)')
    WHERE 
    new.account_id IS NOT NULL AND (SELECT id FROM account WHERE id = new.account_id) IS NULL;
END;

If you use a separate tool like sqliteman, this and others can help you "automate" creating triggers like this that mimic the use of enforcing foreign key constraints.

Comment: Is there a performance improvement over using an if statement to either insert or update? I went this an if statement for now, will try out sqliteman when releasing final version of the app, Thanks.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure (Flex developer background not Db), it would probably be a lot easier in the long run for a lot of tables - but reading the syntax diagram, it doesn't appear to support expressions in that area of the statement. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html